# Найден баг,не работает поиск на странице корректно после вставки функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){
    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    newEl.id = "current";
    newEl.style.cssText = "display:none";
    var tbl = document.querySelector("#knack-logo");

    if(tbl == null){
        return false
    }
    else{
    tbl.before(newEl);
    }
},2000)
window.setInterval (function(){
    var newEl = document.querySelector('#current')
    if(newEl == null){
        return false
    }
    else{
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('tr');             
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var elem = elems[i];
            var z = document.getElementById('current');
                elem.onclick = function() {
                    var id = elem.getAttribute("id");
                    console.log(id);
                   // $('tr').css('border', '1px solid #dbdbdb');
                    $('tr').css('background', 'none');
                    z.innerText = id;
                };
                setInterval(function (){    
                    if(elem.id === z.innerText & elem.id !== "") {
                        //$(elem).css('border', '3px solid black');
                        $(elem).css('background', 'aquamarine');
                    }
                },1000);

        })(i);
    }}
    },100);
```

Цель данной функции подсветка текущего рядка таблицы.Есть таблица,в каждую ячейку можно внести данные и потдвердить.При сабмите таблица выпадает из html и генерируется новая.Что то типо аякса,точно не знаю.
Что может выззвать баг - при нажатии ctrl+f и поиска на странице начинает искать спустя минуту условно и ищет каждый новый элемент спустя тоже минуту.

Comment: Скорее всего ваш скрипт отжирает много памяти, вы 10 раз в секунду генерируете еще пачку `setInterval`, надо перерабатывать логику

Comment: @br3t переработал - все работает

Comment: у тебя использован `setTimeout` вместо `window.onload = function(){};`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С днем рожденьем земли батя, с 99 чем-то летием, наконец-то нашей земле исполнилось 2020 лет

Ты уверен, что таймер, который вешает клик каждую секунду, это хорошая идея?

```js
const sleep=(ms)=>new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, ms));

const init=async()=>{
    while($('#current').length === 0){
        await sleep(1000);
        $('#knack-logo').before(`<div id="current" style="display:none;"></div>`);
    }
    doIt();
    // setInterval(doIt, 1000); // are you sure?
};

const doIt=()=>{
    const $zet = $('#current');
    if($zet.length === 0)return false;

    for(const elem of $('body').find('tr')){
        const $el = $(elem);
        if($el.attr('id') === $zet.text() && $el.attr('id') !== ''){
            $el.css('background', 'aquamarine');
        }
        $el.click(({currentTarget})=>{
            const id = $(currentTarget).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
            $('tr').css('background', 'none');
            $zet.text(id);
        });
    }
};

window.onload=()=>init();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    newEl.id = "current";
    newEl.style.cssText = "display:none";
    var tbl = document.querySelector("#knack-logo");
        if (tbl == null) {
            return false
        }
        else {
        tbl.before(newEl);
        }
}, 4000)


window.setTimeout(function () {
    var z = document.getElementById('current');
        if (z == null) {
        return false
        }
        else {
        window.setInterval(function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    (function (i) {
                        var elem = elems[i];
                            if (elem.id === z.innerText & elem.id !== "") {
                                 //$(elem).css('border', '3px solid black');
                                $(elem).css('background', 'aquamarine');
                            }
                            //При клике
                            elem.onclick = function () {
                                var id = elem.getAttribute("id");
                                console.log(id);
                                // $('tr').css('border', '1px solid #dbdbdb');
                                $('tr').css('background', 'none');
                                z.innerText = id;
                            };
                    })(i);
                }
        }, 1000)
        }//else
}, 3000)
```

Comment: `(function (i) { ... })(i);`, интересно, кто это вас(новичков) так учит писать в цикл?...